# Ubuntu on USB flash drive

Tags: ubuntu, usb, development-environment

I would like to have a portable Ruby on Rails development env running on Linux.
so I could work in parallel to my Windows related activities.

I'm looking for reliable USB flash driver.
what size should I look for?

Are there any recommendations?

Did anyone manage to achieve such things?

Comment: How does this question relate to development ?

Comment: Because he wants to develop in Ruby on Rails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/).

So what you want is a fully capable Ubuntu/Linux environment set up on a USB that you can just plug and use on your computer right?

Basically the steps are simple:

1. Download your desired ubuntu/linux flavour.
2. Make a bootable USB drive and install it using [Universal USB Installer.](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) You can also download your .iso right from the program itself, if you like.
3. Make sure you select a big enough persistent file size to store your changes on the USB. So that you don't lose any data after reboots, etc.

More info: [How to Create a Persistent Bootable Ubuntu USB Flash  Drive](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/)

If you don't want to boot into it and want to use your Windows OS simultaneously, consider using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and check this previous question regarding the same [booting ubuntu from usb using virtualbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1044241/465082)

Comment: I've checked this site.
Do you know some recommended USB brands?
there is no problem using the internet via Ubuntu on a USB flash right?

Comment: Shouldn't be any problem with the internet provided you have the correct drivers installed. As for USB brands, I can't really say it would matter that much. As long as your USB doesn't die, any brand should be good.

Comment: @embedded, StackOverflow isn't really for product recommendations. You could try sites like [NewEgg](http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=522&name=USB-Flash-Drives) or [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/usb-thumb-drive-charts/benchmarks,109.html) for flash drive reviews and recommendations.